# all combinations of all sizes less than N

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics

I want to generate all possible combinations (without duplicates) of all sizes less or equal than \$N\$, so for example if \$N=3\$ I want to generate the following
\$\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},
\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},
\{1,2,3\}.\$

I created the following algorithm in Java. Is there a more optimal way to generate?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = 3;

    for (int k=1; k <= n; k++) {
        System.out.println("of size "+k);
        List<int[]> perms = generateOfSize(k, n);
        System.out.print(perms.size()+": ");
        for(int i=0; i<perms.size(); i++){
            int[] perm = perms.get(i);
            System.out.print(perms.get(i)[0]);
            for(int j=1; j < k; j++){
                System.out.print("-"+perms.get(i)[j]);
            }
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static List<int[]> generateOfSize(int k, int n){
    int[] cur = new int[k];
    List<int[]> all = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    // 1-st step - init
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        cur[i] = i;
    }

    // 2-nd step - do shifts
    do{
        int[] copy = new int[k];
        System.arraycopy( cur, 0, copy, 0, cur.length );
        all.add(copy);
    } while (doShift(cur, k, n));

    return all;
}

public static boolean doShift(int[] cur, int k, int n){
    if (cur[k-1] < n-1){
        cur[k-1] = cur[k-1] + 1;
        return true;
    }
    for(int i = k-1; i > 0; i--){
        if (cur[i] - cur[i-1] > 1) {
            cur[i-1] = cur[i-1] + 1;
            for (int j = i; j < k; j++){
                cur[j] = cur[j-1]+1;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite your implementation much succintly:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int N = 4;

        int globalLineNumber = 1;

        for (int n = 1; n <= N; ++n) {
            int[] combination = IntStream.range(0, n).toArray();
            System.out.println("Combination size: " + n);
            int lineNumber = 1;

            do {
                System.out.printf("[%3d] %3d: %s\n", 
                                  globalLineNumber++,
                                  lineNumber++, 
                                  Arrays.toString(combination));
            } while ((combination = 
                      generateNextCombination(combination, N)) != null);
        }
    }

    public static int[] generateNextCombination(int[] combination, int n) {
        if (combination[combination.length - 1] < n - 1) {
            combination[combination.length - 1]++;
            return combination;
        }

        for (int i = combination.length - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (combination[i] < combination[i + 1] - 1) {
                combination[i]++;

                for (int j = i + 1; j < combination.length; ++j) {
                    combination[j] = combination[j - 1] + 1;
                }

                return combination;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The above produces the following output:

```
Combination size: 1
[  1]   1: [0]
[  2]   2: [1]
[  3]   3: [2]
[  4]   4: [3]
Combination size: 2
[  5]   1: [0, 1]
[  6]   2: [0, 2]
[  7]   3: [0, 3]
[  8]   4: [1, 2]
[  9]   5: [1, 3]
[ 10]   6: [2, 3]
Combination size: 3
[ 11]   1: [0, 1, 2]
[ 12]   2: [0, 1, 3]
[ 13]   3: [0, 2, 3]
[ 14]   4: [1, 2, 3]
Combination size: 4
[ 15]   1: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Basically, you are given \$N\$ - the number of all possible items you can choose. Also, you are given \$n\$ - the number of \$N\$ items you actually put in a combination. Now, you have a simple class method for producing the next \$n\$-combination. Whenever all \$n\$-combinations where generated, return **`null`** in order to signal that you are done with them, after which increment \$n\$, generate the first lexicographic combination, and keep generating until **`null`**.

Hope that helps.

**Addition**

Of course, instead of **`combination`** and **`null`** you could return **`true`** or **`false`** depending on the case whether the input combination was successfully "incremented" towards the next combination or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty cool, efficient algorithm to generate permutations.
I have just a few tips on technique.

#### Simplifications

Instead of this:

> ```
> int[] copy = new int[k];
> System.arraycopy( cur, 0, copy, 0, cur.length );
> all.add(copy);
> ```

You can simply write:

```
all.add(cur.clone());
```

---

Instead of this:

> ```
> cur[k-1] = cur[k-1] + 1;
> ```

You can simplify with `++`:

```
cur[k-1]++;
```

---

Instead of this:

> ```
> int[] perm = perms.get(i);
> System.out.print(perms.get(i)[0]);
> for(int j=1; j < k; j++){
>     System.out.print("-"+perms.get(i)[j]);
> ```

Why not simply reuse `perm`?

```
int[] perm = perms.get(i);
System.out.print(perm[0]);
for(int j=1; j < k; j++){
    System.out.print("-"+perm[j]);
```

#### Method decomposition

This code within `generateOfSize` would be better to move into its own method:

> ```
> int[] cur = new int[k];
>
> // 1-st step - init
> for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
>     cur[i] = i;
> }
> ```

Or if you can use Java8, then you can use `IntStream.range(0, n).toArray();` as in @Coderodde's answer.

The code inside `main` could be moved in its own method too.

#### Naming

Your method and variable names could be improved. Some ideas:

- `doShift` -> `shiftCombination`
- `cur` -> `combination`

#### Formatting

The formatting is too compact. Add some spaces around operators. For example the `main` method becomes much more readable when auto-reformatted with an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 3;

    for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        System.out.println("of size " + k);
        List<int[]> perms = generateOfSize(k, n);
        System.out.print(perms.size() + ": ");
        for (int i = 0; i < perms.size(); i++) {
            int[] perm = perms.get(i);
            System.out.print(perms.get(i)[0]);
            for (int j = 1; j < k; j++) {
                System.out.print("-" + perms.get(i)[j]);
            }
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```